# XML XSLT local-name not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

I am trying to extract the string after ":" in the node name and assign it as field name but my XSLT below doesn't seem to work right.

Here is my **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<oai_dc:dc xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/">

<dc:title>valley</dc:title>
<dc:creator>jhdjsdh</dc:creator>
<dc:subject>tree</dc:subject>

</oai_dc:dc>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/">

<xsl:template match="/">  
<xsl:for-each select="oai_dc:dc/*">

  <field>
     <xsl:attribute name="name">
       <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </field>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I would like to achieve but **unable** to with above XSLT:

```
<field name="title"> valley </field>
<field name="creator"> jhdjsdh</field>
<field name="subject"> tree </field>
```

Comment: I ran your sample XML and XSLT unchanged, through XSLTPROC and got the results okay.  (Mind you, the result is not a valid XML document, as you do not create a root element.)  What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Hi. I tested it using this online XSLT processor - http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.htm

Comment: Yes, I can see the values but I want to print the field names as well. For above example, I want to see field names as "title", "creator", etc. as opposed to an empty value or "dc.title", "dc.creator"

Comment: I get a 404 trying to use your link to freeformatter.com, but I did try xsltransform.net and your stylesheet worked fine using Xalan. (I did add an `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute to `xsl:stylesheet` though). http://xsltransform.net/bdxtr5

Comment: What's the output you're getting?  Ditto on @DanielHaley's comment.

Comment: You missed the L in HTML in your link to http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

So, I ran your code there, and the problem was, like I said, that your output is not an XML document -- no root level element.

Add an `<out>` right after `<xsl:template match="/">` and a `</out>` right before `</xsl:template>` and try it again.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you all. exclude-result-prefixes did the trick in getting what I wanted.

Comment: @bjimba: +1 you are right about root level element. thanks!

Comment: @DanielHaley Could you post your comment as an answer? I can accept it. exclude-result-prefixes gave me the field names

Comment: @sunskin  "*exclude-result-prefixes gave me the field names*" That's not what  `exclude-result-prefixes` does. Make sure you're using a decent tool to do your testing; the one at freeformatter.com is extremely buggy.

Comment: Thanks Michael. yes, I realized that about freeformatter.com. exclude-result-prefixes helped me get rid of prefixes from field names. Is that not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a 404 trying to use your link to freeformatter.com, but I did try xsltransform.net and your stylesheet worked fine using Xalan. (I did add an exclude-result-prefixes attribute to xsl:stylesheet though)....

[xsltransform.net/bdxtr5](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtr5)

Also note that you can simplify the attribute creation by using an attribute value template ([AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)) instead of `xsl:attribute`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="dc oai_dc">

    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xsl:for-each select="oai_dc:dc/*">
            <field name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </field>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't quite understand the significance of curly braces though. Looked at the link but not 100% clear. Got it working but would you explain what difference the curly brances make?

Comment: another quick question - how can I use curly braces, if I would like to add a custom prefix. e.g. <field name= concat ($prefix, local-name()) /> where $prefix => <xsl:param name="prefix"> qq.</xsl:param>

Comment: @sunskin - Basically whatever is inside the curly braces gets evaluated and the results are used as the value. So for your example, it would be `<field name="{concat($prefix,local-name())}"/>`